# Custom workspace in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

1. I am not getting the check box to select **custom workspace** in Jenkins(ver. 1.465) while configuring the job, is there any plugin to get it?
2. After getting check box how to **configure** (path of workspace)?

Comment: In 2017, the correct answer is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271867/209406

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. For a maven build, the option "Use custom workspace"  is in Build Section ("Advanced" button)

Answer (score 13):

in the general tab, when you go to the "advanced options" , you will see the "custom workspace" option

Comment: It's placed at a place really not obvious

Answer (score 6):

A couple of images to clarify how to configure a custom workspace directory.

The "Advanced" button to click to show the "Workspace Root Directory" option:

[image: The "Advanced" button to click to show the "Workspace Root Directory" option]

Use a root directory with `${ITEM_FULLNAME}` to put your projects' workspaces under a custom directory:
[image: Use a root directory with <code>${ITEM_FULLNAME}</code> to put your projects' workspaces under a custom directory]

Comment: Do you know how to get the list of all variables available?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use custom workspace choose freestyle or multi-configuration option, Custom workspace option is not supported in maven-project(From new item)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this answer comes a little bit too late but, anyway:

- Jenkins v2.13, works on v1.652
- Maven project
- Build section
- Click on Advanced button on the right side of the page
- Check "Use custom workspace"
- Fill in the path to the desired folder

Supports parameters too: ${SVN_BRANCH}