# one source folder for multiple configuration of build item in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build a big Project hosted on git repository whose source code is few GBs. I'm building it for multiple platforms.
currently my build folder looks like this:

```
-workspace
  -configuration
    -A
      -<source is checked out here> + build here
    -B
      -<source is checked out here> + build here
    -C
      -<source is checked out here> + build here
```

and the source is cloned for all three configurations under the build folder.
What I want is to have something like the following:

```
-workspace
  -<source is checked out here>
  -configuration
    -A
      -out of tree build here
    -B
      -out of tree build here
    -C
      -out of tree build here
```

The source code will be checked out directly under the workspace, and my build configuration will perform an out of tree build in the configuration directory.

How can I achieve this using jenkins and git plugin configurations?

Comment: seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520475/same-work-space-for-multiple-jobs

Comment: it is not a duplicate, as the link you posted asks about same workspace for multiple projects, while I'm asking about same source folder for multiple configurations of a single project