# How to set common workspace dir for multiple jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I'm trying to migrate from Hudson to Jenkins and faced a problem.
All of my test jobs (huge number) are using *Build -> Invoke Ant* parameter *Build File* with relative path and it is the same for all of them.
So they should all use the same workspace directory.

I've set it up in *Workspace Root Directory* in Jenkins *Configure System*.

Example:

- Real `run.xml` file location: `C:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\trunk\Eb\run.xml`
- Workspace Root Directory: `C:\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\trunk\`
- Build File parameter (in job): `Eb\run.xml`

Build fails with:

`ERROR: Unable to find build script at C:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/trunk/workspace/run BD CompletedPath (firefox) ~regression/Eb/run.xml`

As you see Jenkins adds job name to it anyway, so the path is incorrect and build fails. If I set up absolute paths all works fine, but it's illogically and a large number of copy-paste work.

Please help to sort it out without modifying all the jobs, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same work space for multiple jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520475/same-work-space-for-multiple-jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Shared workspace plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shared+workspace+plugin):

> This plugin allows to share workspaces by Jenkins jobs with the same SCM repos.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx! On my personal note I could also add [ConfigurationSlicingPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) as an option (I didn't notice that my previous Hudson setup had been using this plugin).