# Prevent Jenkins to rebuild the entire project everytime

Tags: git, jenkins, ant

Sometimes I have to start my Jenkins manually (when I add some new plugins for example) to make sure it works properly. Normally, a build is setup to run at midnight.

In order to work faster, I would like to know, if I could start a build with Jenkins, without having to go through the whole process : pull from git, clear from database, composer update etc...

Because I am only adding features to Jenkins, and not the source code itself.

I use ant to build my project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the job type you build, you should be able to specify a certain directory in the file system as workspace location. Then you can just do a rebuild of you program. Depending on your make tool this should just rebuild files changed this the last build, e.g. do to the git pull.

See e.g. https://ingorichter.blogspot.de/2012/02/jenkins-change-workspaces-and-build.html and [Custom workspace in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537137/custom-workspace-in-jenkins)

Comment: I dont think you understood my question. I dont want to build Jenkins in a custom workspace, I want to prevent Jenkins from rebuilding the entire project itself, when the source code is exactly the same.

Comment: Then are you using a pipeline script or another type of job? Normally Jenkins will poll regularly for changes at the repository and if there is a change will start a build of the job. If I understand you correctly, we want to manually start the job, and then Jenkins should decide if it really needs to do a build?

Comment: At my workplace, we re not really doing things that way actually. Lots of things are being pushed on our repository, so we set up jenkins to build periodically every evening. So during the day, I would like to be able to start Jenkins without him to rebuild the project, because the point is not to test our code, but Jenkins plugins.